# open one level deep sub-menu, only, on each click using jquery OR javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

> The issue I am having is:

when I click on "menu2", it is showing me sub-menu and all options of sub-menu.

> Expected result:

click on "menu2" should open "sub-menu2" only and NO "sub-menu2" options.
click on ""sub-menu2" should open all it's children.

I see there are some question on related to this one but I did not find any question similar to mine.
If you can suggest a way to do this in pure JS/ES that would be great. Currently I am using jQuery.

```js
 $('.container > ul > li').on('click', function(){
      $('ul',this).toggle(200);
  })
```

```css
   div.container > ul ul{
            display:none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  <ul>
      <li>menu1
          <ul>
              <li>testA</li>
              <li>testB</li>
              <li>testC</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>menu2
          <ul>
              <li>
                  sub-menu2
                  <ul>
                    <li>issue1</li>
                    <li>issue2</li>
                    <li>issue3</li>
                  </u1>
            </li>
              
          </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using toggling immediate children and stop event propagation.

```js
     $('.container li').on('click', function(event){
     
     
        
        $(this).children("ul").toggle(200)
         
        event.stopPropagation() 
      })
```

```css
      
      .menu ul {
       
        display:none;
       }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <div class="container">
      <ul>
          <li class ="menu">menu1
              <ul>
                  <li>testA</li>
                  <li>testB</li>
                  <li>testC</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class ="menu">menu2
              <ul>
                  <li>
                      sub-menu2
                      <ul>
                        <li>issue1</li>
                        <li>issue2</li>
                        <li>issue3</li>
                      </ul>
                 </li>
                  
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

YOu just need to use your selector a bit different way, and its done, if need something else, pls let me know

```js
$('.container li').on('click', function(e) {
        var ckeckChildVisiblity = $(this).find('>ul').is(':visible');
        if (!ckeckChildVisiblity) {
            $(this).find('>ul').slideDown();
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).find('>ul').slideUp();
            return false;
        }
    })
```

```css
div.container > ul ul{
            display:none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  <ul>
      <li>menu1
          <ul>
              <li>testA</li>
              <li>testB</li>
              <li>testC</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>menu2
          <ul>
              <li>
                  sub-menu2
                  <ul>
                    <li>issue1</li>
                    <li>issue2</li>
                    <li>issue3</li>
                  </u1>
            </li>
              
          </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: menu and submenu cannot be closed

Comment: you want to close it in the same way? on lcick of its parent text

Comment: you can see the `toggle` method in the default code of the author. this means that all all submenus and menus should have the opposite effect when clicked again.

Comment: I just saw that the comment is not done by the author, if he needs it he will ask or it, my friend

Comment: just added code for that as well, Thanks for this, but I am not sure if he needs it,